# Problems with updating JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am writing a simple card game GUI with a JTextArea to display what is happening and who placed which card and so on. After I finished the layout, I added a method to append the text to the JTextArea character by character, so it has a nice writing effect. I have a class for creating the window and GUI, and a class for the game and the output to the TextArea.

This works however only for initializing the game. After that the player has to choose a card by pressing a button and when he does, I call a method within the game object so that it goes on. The problem here is it waits until the actionEvent from the button press is performed and then updates the TextArea with all text that the game processed without updating it character by character. Just adding textArea.update(... after every character doesnt solve the problem because the area begins to flicker.

Here is my window class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;


public class window {

    private JFrame frmStinkt;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JTable table;
    private static ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    private JTextField textField;
    private static WindowGame newGame;
    private static int test = 0;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    window window = new window(104, 4);
    window.frmStinkt.setVisible(true);
    newGame = new WindowGame(104, 4, window.textArea, window.table);
    newGame.initGame();
    setButtonNames(newGame.players.get(0).cards);
    window.enableButtons();
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public window(int numberOfCards, int numberOfRows)
{
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */


private void initialize() {
    Font defaultFont = new Font("Gill Sans MT",Font.BOLD,14);

    frmStinkt = new JFrame();
    frmStinkt.setTitle("6 STINKT!");
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frmStinkt.setBounds(400, 200, 600, 450);
    frmStinkt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBorder(null);
    scrollPane.setBounds(83, 18, 420, 130);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 255, 0), 2, true));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.BOLD, 13));

    label = new JLabel("CARDS");
    label.setEnabled(false);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    label.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    label.setFont(defaultFont);
    label.setBounds(254, 264, 78, 23);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(label);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    table.setGridColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    table.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    table.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 255, 0)));
    table.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    table.setBounds(165, 160, 255, 64);
    table.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.BOLD, 14));
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(table);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setEditable(false);
    textField.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    textField.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField.setBounds(277, 235, 32, 25);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.setBounds(10, 284, 564, 66);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton button0 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button0);
    button0.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button0.setVisible(false);
            test = buttons.indexOf(button0);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(0)));
            disableButtons();
            newGame.HumanTurn(test);
            buttons.remove(0);
        }
    });
    button0.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button0.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button0.setFont(defaultFont);
    button0.setOpaque(true);
    button0.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button0.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    buttons.add(button0);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button1);
    button1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(1);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(1)));
            disableButtons();
            panel.remove(button0);
        }
    });
    button1.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button1.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button1.setFont(defaultFont);
    button1.setOpaque(true);
    button1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button1);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button2);
    button2.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(2);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(2)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button2.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button2.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button2.setFont(defaultFont);
    button2.setOpaque(true);
    button2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button2);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button3);
    button3.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(3);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(3)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button3.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button3.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button3.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button3.setFont(defaultFont);
    button3.setOpaque(true);
    button3.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button3);

    JButton button4 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button4);
    button4.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(4);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(4)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button4.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button4.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button4.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button4.setFont(defaultFont);
    button4.setOpaque(true);
    button4.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button4);

    JButton button5 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button5);
    button5.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(5);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(5)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button5.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button5.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button5.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button5.setFont(defaultFont);
    button5.setOpaque(true);
    button5.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button5);

    JButton button6 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button6);
    button6.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(6);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(6)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button6.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button6.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button6.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button6.setFont(defaultFont);
    button6.setOpaque(true);
    button6.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button6);

    JButton button7 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button7);
    button7.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(7);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(7)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button7.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button7.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button7.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button7.setFont(defaultFont);
    button7.setOpaque(true);
    button7.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button7);

    JButton button8 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button8);
    button8.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(8);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(8)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button8.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button8.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button8.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button8.setFont(defaultFont);
    button8.setOpaque(true);
    button8.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button8);

    JButton button9 = new JButton("---");
    panel.add(button9);
    button9.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame.HumanTurn(9);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(9)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    button9.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    button9.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    button9.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    button9.setFont(defaultFont);
    button9.setOpaque(true);
    button9.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(button9);

    JButton random_1 = new JButton("RANDOM");
    random_1.setBounds(238, 361, 105, 25);
    frmStinkt.getContentPane().add(random_1);
    random_1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    random_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int random = (int)(Math.random() * newGame.players.get(0).cards.size());
            newGame.HumanTurn(random);
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(newGame.players.get(0).cards.get(random)));
            disableButtons();
        }
    });
    random_1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    random_1.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    random_1.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    random_1.setFont(defaultFont);
    random_1.setOpaque(true);
    random_1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttons.add(random_1);

    disableButtons();
}

public void enableButtons()
{
    for(int i=0; i<buttons.size(); i++)
        buttons.get(i).setEnabled(true);
    label.setEnabled(true);
}

public void disableButtons()
{
    for(int i=0; i<buttons.size(); i++)
        buttons.get(i).setEnabled(false);
    label.setEnabled(false);
}

public static void setButtonNames(ArrayList<Integer> cards)
{
    for(int i=0; i<buttons.size() - 1; i++)
        buttons.get(i).setText(cards.get(i).toString());
}
}
```

I have read that I probably could work around this by using a swingWorker. I found a useful demo for a progressBar, but I can't figure out how to use it with my approach. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Here the method which is called by the button press and print:

```
public void HumanTurn(int cardIndex)
{
    print("Du hast " + players.get(0).cards.get(cardIndex) + " gewählt.", textSpeedNormal);
    next += 1;
    BotTurn();
}

public void print(String text, int speed)
{
    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        textArea.append(text.substring(i, (i+1)));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    textArea.append("\n");
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

Comment: `The problem here is it waits until the actionEvent from the button press is performed and then updates the TextArea with all text that the game processed without updating it character by character` - and you didn't post that code so we have no idea what you are doing. Also, why did you repeat the button code 9 times? Create a method and pass a parameter to the method.

Comment: I build the GUI with windowbuilder in eclipse, so the code for the buttons was auto-generated. The button press calls a method in game with the selected card number as parameter. The game then prints text to be displayed in the JTextArea.

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate your windows and code. As you can see you are not in control of the design of your code. Use the IDE to help compile and debug etc.

Comment: I will remember that ^^ 
Its the first time i made a GUI so thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep(speed);
```

Don't use Thread.sleep(...).

This puts the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` to sleep so the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Instead use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation. The Swing Timer replaces the looping code. Every time the timer fires you do some Action, in this case add a character to the text area.

One way might be to add the text to a `StringBuilder`. Then every time the Timer fires you remove the first character from the StringBuilder and append it to the text area. When the StringBuilder is empty you stop the Timer.